# Cannot generate drop down from nested json and filter it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Am trying to populate drop down from a json as per below code and filter them.
I could achieve for direct fields but could't get the dropdown loaded for nested fields. Once the two drop down are populated, I would like to filter them to see the list of pid's for each combination.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
Location: <select id="Location" name="Location"></select>
Category: <select id="Category" name="Category"></select>

<button onclick="javascript:getcount()">Search</button>
<div id="result" style="color:#0094ff;font-size:20px;margin-top:100px;">
    Number of Users found : <div id="res"></div>
</div>
<div id="detailedresult" style="color:#0094ff;font-size:20px;margin-top:100px;">
    PID's : <div id="pidRes"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsonList = {
        "Users": [{ "pid": "2", "loc": "Bangalore",  "cat": [{ "dname": "Hotels" }, { "dname":"Travel" }, { "dname":"Banking" }] },
            { "pid": "3", "loc": "Chennai", "cat": [{ "dname":"Hotels" }, { "dname":"Travel" }, { "dname":"Banking" }] },
            { "pid": "4", "loc": "Delhi", "cat": [{ "dname":"Hotels" }, { "dname":"Travel" }, { "dname":"Healthcare" }] },
             { "pid": "5", "loc": "Hyderabad", "cat": [{ "dname":"Retail" }, { "dname":"Insurance" }, { "dname":"Banking" }] },
             { "pid": "6", "loc": "Hyderabad", "cat": [{ "dname":"Ecommerce"},{"dname":"Banking"},{"dname":"Healthcare"},{"dname":"Travel"},] }]
       }

$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = Object.keys(jsonList.Users).length
    $('#res').html(count);

    var listItems= "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.Users.length; i++){
        listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonList.Users[i].pid + "'>" + jsonList.Users[i].loc + "</option>";
    }
    $("#Location").html(listItems);

    var listItems3 = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.Users['cat']['dname'].length; i++) {
        listItems2 += "<option value='" + jsonList.Users[i].pid + "'>" + jsonList.Users[i].cat.dname + "</option>";
    }
    $("#Category").html(listItems3);
}
);

function getcount()
{
    var loc = document.getElementById('Location').value;
    var cat = document.getElementById('Category').value;
    var count = Object.keys(jsonList.Users).length // Where condition required.. when Location and Category are available.. For each combination (Location + Category), how many users and what are the pid's
    $('#res').html(count);
}
</script>
```

What am I missing in above code for Category drop down generation ?

How can I filter the json based on location and category values (List of respective pid's for each combination) ?

**EDIT:**

**Requirement:**

First: List of pid's who are from Location 'Bangalore' AND has category 'Banking' (Resultant pid = 2)

Second: List of pid's who are either from Chennai OR has category Ecommerce category (Resultant pid => 3,6)

Comment: Are you trying to populate the cities on load, then, based on the selection, populate the category?

Comment: no dependency for category on location.. I would want to know the total count of pid's and the list of pid's for combination of location+category

Comment: you asked for "count of pid's and pid's for each combination" There is only 1 pid for each location. Not sure what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but here is a working set of dropdowns that populate based on the json provided. You may have been looking for this loop to populate the categories

```
 for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.Users.length; i++){
    listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonList.Users[i].pid + "' data-ind='"+i+"'>" + jsonList.Users[i].loc + "</option>";
    pidres+= "Location: " +jsonList.Users[i].loc+ ". PID: " +jsonList.Users[i].pid+ ". Number of categories: " +jsonList.Users[i].cat.length + "<br />"

    //loop all cats
    for (var j = 0; j < jsonList.Users[i].cat.length; j++) {

    listItems3 += "<option value='" + jsonList.Users[i].cat[j].dname + "'>" + jsonList.Users[i].cat[j].dname + "</option>";


  }
}

//then to filter the results
 $("#Category > option").each(function () {
if(usedNames[this.text]) {
    $(this).remove();
} else {
    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
}
```

});

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vpc7n3d/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Cory!.. I will write the button click event to display the list of pid for each combination of dropdown values